# Translating from jsp to servlet in jsp?

Tags: jsp

In JSP, JSP is converted into servlet.My question when this translation occurs i.e at the time of first request only or for every request?

Answer (score 0):

It's compiled on first request into servlet .java code, after which it's compiled into Java byte code and the .class file is loaded by the class loader.

You can usually precompile JSPs using a JSP compiler for your Java EE app server if you're concerned about that delay for the first access.

Comment: Ok i know this.But after  completion of first request if second request came for the already generated servlet what happens whether only generated servlet invokes or jsp invokes i.e all the process will continue form the begining(compile,loading,intilising the servlet)

Comment: No, once you have the .class file loaded into the JVM it's just called as necessary.

Comment: No.I do not get the answer properly.Plz explain clearly the sequential steps i.e what happens at the time of first request for a jsp page(say a1.jsp).Now it is removed from the container.Next another request cam for the same jsp(a1.jsp).Now my question is whether genarated servlet(in the first request) loads the container directly or again jsp is converted into servlet?

Comment: No, the .jsp is not converted into servlet a second time.  Once it's done, you've got it.  One to a customer.  Is that clear enough?  I don't know what your "removed from the container" comment means.  I doubt that you do.  Once a JSP is turned into a servlet, its lifecycle is managed by the container just like every other servlet.  JSP is just a templating language for servlets.

Comment: After servicing the request the servlet is removed from the container.Thats what i said in the above.While sevicing the first request if another request came for the same servlet then container creates a thread and allocates that thread to second request.Is this right one?